# How to make the jQuery background animation smoother

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to do a simple background animation using jQuery. But the animation is not smooth. How can I make it smooth ?  Following is the code and the image that is being used has a size of 4288 X 3216 px

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>bg</title>
    <style>
    #mydiv
    {
        background:url(bg2.jpg) repeat-x;
        height:900px;
        width:100%;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="mydiv">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bgpos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready (function()
            {
                move();


    function move()
    {
        $('#mydiv').animate({"backgroundPosition":"+=5"},100,"linear",move);
    };


    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sJQFx/) seem to work

Comment: @AlexBall , +1 for placehold.it, i just spend to much time re-sizing an image to make my fiddle work

Comment: @helmus ;-) Ya is a cool for 'images' resources (I've find it on twitter bootstrap thumbnail example page).

Answer (score 0):

Here is smooth animation sample with background-position usage:

**[jsFiddle example to play with.](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/37/)**

```
$(document).ready (function() {
 $('div').bind({
  mouseenter: function() {
   $(this).stop().animate({'background-position-y':'-20px','height':'68px'},600);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
   $(this).stop().animate({'background-position-y':'-58px','height':'30px'},600);
  }
 });​
});
```

### ---------

Here is [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) structure example:

```
.animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )
//i didn't use easing here

$('#mydiv').stop().animate({'background-position-y':'-2px','height':'6px'},200,  
   function() {
      $('#mydiv').stop().animate({'background-position-x':'-20px'},200);
      //this will initualise when animate complete
   }
);
```

- [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) used for preventing conflict for same event triggered at
  the same time.
- background-position animate define: 'background-position-y' &
  'background-position-x'
- you can use `,` for multiple animate declarations.
- end 200 for duration, this is important for smooth anitamion.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is probably to large in filesize, lower the quality to a reasonable web size ( 100kb ) and it should run smooth.

( my fiddle, picture is 100kb )
http://fiddle.jshell.net/EuwGb/

Comment: Yeah, when the image size is small the animation works smoother. I also tried with the same image you are using in jsfiddle. But that too  have the same problem.

Comment: Chrome 21.0.1180.75 m, Firefox 13.0.1, IE 8